# PhpStorm CodeIgniter class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, phpstorm, code-completion

Can you help me on this one. I'm new in CodeIgniter and PhpStorm, I'm having a problem. The PhpStorm IDE is showing an error, even though the code works fine (the `Persons`(controller) class can't find the `Person`(model) class).

[image]

[image]

[image]

`$data['persons']=$this->**person**->get_person();` = on this syntax from `Persons` class, there is a message "Field `person` not found in class `Persons`".

Can you enlighten me on how to resolve this, but actually the output is good and it retrieves the data without issue just a warning message in `Persons` class.

Comment: Is your model class named correctly? CodeIgniter has rules on naming/casing. Also, you have the constructor in there, right?

Comment: The name of my model class is "Person" while my controller is "Persons".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this `/* @var \person $data */` ? DAs I understand you what to declare `$data` variable as an instance of `Person` class. Or something else?

Answer (score 19):

The `person` property (`$this->property`) is not explicitly declared as it is created and accessed via PHP's magic methods.

PhpStorm has no special support for CodeIgniter framework and cannot guess where `$this->person` is coming from and what type it is.

But you can help IDE -- just a small PHPDoc comment before the actual class -- using **@property** tag.

```
/**
 * @property Person $person Optional description 
 */
class Persons extends CI_Controller {
```

...and oh magic -- it works:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The answer from LazyOne did not work for me initially. After some testing I found out that my issue was upper/lower case related on how you declare the property in PHPDoc - hopefully the following observations can help someone else. This is what I have to declare my model class:

```
class Custom extends CI_Model {}
```

In my controller I load and use the model for example the following way:

```
$this->load->model('Custom')
$table = $this->Custom->get();
```

Now for phpStorm to pick up this class correctly I originally added a PHPDoc @property comment above a core class as described by others (either above the CI_Controller class or separate CI_phpStrom.php file) like this:

```
*
* @property Custom $custom
*
```

However, this didn't remove the issue, as the variable name becomes case sensitive in this case and I had to write:

```
*
* @property Custom $Custom
*
```

for my above controller code to pick up the class correctly. An alternative would be to use lowercase when calling functions (this works even if your model declaration used uppercase)

```
$this->load->model('custom')
$table = $this->custom->get();
```

The funny thing all this uppercase or lowercase didn't matter if I call my model class "Custom_model" - then it made no change if set the PHPDoc property variable to $Custom_model or $custom_model ...

Answer (score -1):

Normally most people add the ‘`_model`’ suffix to the `Model` class names. I suggest that you rename your model with "Person_model" call your model "person_model" like this:

```
$this->load->model('person_model');
$this->person_model->get_person();
```

I think that you might find it an adequate solution!

Comment: I tried changing my Model Class' name to "person_model" but nothing has changed.

Comment: I think the problem is on phpstorm because I retrieved the data successfully.

Comment: I think the problem is your question isn't clear. You're asking about an *IDE ERROR* not an actual code problem, right? That isn't very clear.

Comment: No, it is PHPStorm, No need to add extra _model against every model class name. `LazyOne` is right, just use phpdoc comments and it will be fine.